# How can I load a URL without reloading the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I saw some work around Internet like this:

```
<a href="./someplace.html"> Link </a>
```

usually it will be open the link or if JS not active:

```
http://www.domain.com/someplace.html
```

but when JS active, it's open like this and load external page into same page without page refreshing:

```
http://www.domain.com/#/someplace.html
```

How is it possible? Can someone help?

I tried to Google it first, also search this website, but haven't found a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        href = $this.attr("href");

    $(document.body).load(href);

    location.href = "#" + href;
});
```

See [jQuery.fn.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

What you supplied as an example in your question relates to the **hash**.

The hash is a hyperlink reference internal to the current document.

When you see a link using `file.html#name_of_smth` it is likely that an anchor in that page looks something like `<a name='name_of_smth'>blah</a>`.

This is not necessarily a JavaScript thing, it can be used if you construct the anchor with a hash and a name such as exemplified [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links_bookmarks.asp).

If you want to use it via JavaScript all you need to do is to modify `window.location.hash`.

The way FaceBook and other sites do it now is *better*. They use AJAX to reload data into the page (as exemplified by other answers here) and they use `window.history.pushState()` as exemplified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/) to inform the browser that the new data belongs to a different url. This changes the url in the address bar with no reload and allows for correct bookmarking and reloading/refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You do it by requesting the new page with [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX), and then insert the content into your current page.

Wrote more details about this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202719/lifehacker-implemention-of-url-change-with-ajax/8203013#8203013).