# Open a link without a page reload

Tags: ajax

When I click on the link i want **page2.html** to appear without any reloading of the current page. Despite all trials, when i click on the link it does reload the entire page before displaying page2.html

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
      var $this = $(this),
        url = $this.data("url");

      $(document.body).load(url);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }); < /script>
```

**homepage.html**

```html
<a href="#" data-url="page2.html" class="topic-list-item">

  <h3 class="topic-title">Internet Protocol Basics</h3>

  <div class="topic-description-text">
    Learn how Internet Protocol is used
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: `function(data)` should be something like `function(data){ $('.myDiv').html(data)}`

Comment: do you want to replace full html or just the content of div

Comment: @Virendrayadav the full html...  i want page1 to be replaced by page2 but without reload

Comment: @DLeh still doesn't work

Comment: `$("a").click(function(){ return false;...`

Answer (score 0):

Set Up the Stream Progress Bar

```html
<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Implementing JavaScript Routes :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const progressBar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
  // Update the progress bar width based on the loading percentage
  function updateProgressBar(percentage) {
    progressBar.style.width = `${percentage}%`;
    progressBar.classList.add("filled");
    // hide progress bar when content is loaded
    if (percentage == 100) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        progressBar.classList.remove("filled");
        progressBar.style.width = 0;
      }, 300);
    }
  }
  // Fetch content based on the URL and update the page
  function fetchContent(url) {
    updateProgressBar(0); // Reset progress bar
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
      },
      mode: "cors",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
        const total = +response.headers.get("Content-Length");
        let loaded = 0;
        let html = "";
        function read() {
          reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
            if (done) {
              const parser = new DOMParser();
              const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
              // Extract the specific HTML element and their child's from the parsed document
              const primary = doc.querySelector("#primary");
              // take content element from current page
              const appContainer = document.getElementById("content");
              // Then, Remove all child elements
              while (appContainer.firstChild) {
                appContainer.removeChild(appContainer.firstChild);
              }
              // Append a new element
              appContainer.appendChild(primary);
              updateProgressBar(100); // Set progress bar to 100% when content is loaded
              return;
            }
            loaded += value.length;
            updateProgressBar((loaded / total) * 100);
            const chunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
            html += chunk;
            // Process the content here if needed
            // somthing like pelase wait or spinner..
            read(); // Continue reading the stream
          });
        }
        read();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        updateProgressBar(0); // Reset progress bar in case of errors
      });
  }
  // Handle link clicks
  function handleLinkClick(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    // Check if the clicked element or its parent is an anchor element
    const anchor = target.closest("a");
    if (anchor) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Get the href attribute of the anchor element
      const targetUrl = anchor.getAttribute("href");
      // Update the URL and push a new history state
      history.pushState(null, "", targetUrl);
      // Fetch and load the content for the clicked link
      fetchContent(targetUrl);
    }
  }
  // Attach click event listeners to all links
  const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  allLinks.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", handleLinkClick);
  });
  // Handle the popstate event to update the page when the user navigates back/forward
  window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
    fetchContent(window.location.href);
  });
});
```

In the above code, we first attach an event listener to the `DOMContentLoaded` event to ensure our JavaScript code runs when the page has finished loading.

The `handleLinkClick` function is responsible for intercepting link clicks, preventing the default behavior, starting the progress bar animation, and fetching the content for the clicked link using the `fetchContent` function.

The `fetchContent` function sends a GET request to the target URL, retrieves the response as text, stops the progress bar animation, and updates the content container with the fetched HTML.

Make sure to have a CSS file linked to your HTML, where you can define the styles for the progress bar animation. Here's a basic CSS example for the progress bar:

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.progress-bar.filled {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Optional: Add animation to the progress bar */
@keyframes progress-animation {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Feel free to customize the CSS styles to match your website's design.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("a").click(function() {
var $this = $(this),
    href = $this.attr("href");

$(document.body).load(href);

location.href = "#" + href;
});
```

See [jQuery.fn.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more details.

Comment: But I have 10 such link, will i have to repeat this code 10 times ?

Comment: try removing this part `location.href = "#" + href;`

Comment: @MancharyManchaary still no.

Comment: Give credit to the answer you copy-pasted. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11601219/7383506

Answer (score -1):

try this code it will work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function (event) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    url = $this.data("url");

                $(document.body).load(url);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

the problem with Digital's code is that he is not using data function to get url as well when we click on  then default action for anchor will be called so we need to stop default action so i used event.preventDefault();

also always put your jquery code between $(document).ready block

Comment: I really don't understand why it is not working. page2.html is not opening.

Comment: i created a a demo on local system, it is working fine

Comment: you can see in console to check any javascript related error , is your jquery properly added in your page

Comment: `<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("a").click(function (event) {
      var $this = $(this),
       url = $this.data("url");

      $(document.body).load(url);
      event.preventDefault();
     });
    });
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <a href="#" data-url="new.html">Internet Protocol Basics</a>
</body>
</html>`